# How do i check for duplicate entries before i add an entry the dictionary

Tags: python

Given i have the following dictionary which stores key(entry_id),value(entry_body,entry_title) pairs.

```
"entries": {
    "1": {
            "body": "ooo",
            "title": "jack"
        },
    "2": {
            "body": "ooo",
            "title": "john"
        }
}
```

How do i check whether the title of an entry that i want to add to the dictionary already exists.
For example: This is the new entry that i want to add.

```
{
    "body": "nnnn",
    "title": "jack"
}
```

Comment: I would redesign data structure and made `title` a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Christian König's answer, your data structure seems like it could be made clearer and more efficient.  Still, if you need a solution to this setup in particular, here's one that will work - and it automatically adds new integer keys to the `entries` dict.

I've added an extra case to show both a rejection and an accepted update.

```
def existing_entry(e, d):
    return [True for entry in d["entries"].values() if entry["title"] == e["title"]]

def update_entries(e, entries):
    if not any(existing_entry(e, entries)):
        current_keys = [int(x) for x in list(entries["entries"].keys())]
        next_key = str(max(current_keys) + 1)
        entries["entries"][next_key] = e
        print("Updated:", entries)
    else:
        print("Existing entry found.")

update_entries(new_entry_1, data)
update_entries(new_entry_2, data)
```

Output:

```
Existing entry found.
Updated: 
{'entries': 
    {'1': {'body': 'ooo', 'title': 'jack'}, 
     '2': {'body': 'ooo', 'title': 'john'}, 
     '3': {'body': 'qqqq', 'title': 'jill'}
    }
}
```

Data:

```
data = {"entries": {"1": {"body": "ooo", "title": "jack"},"2": {"body": "ooo","title": "john"}}}
new_entry_1 = {"body": "nnnn", "title": "jack"}
new_entry_2 = {"body": "qqqq", "title": "jill"}
```

Answer (score 8):

Have you thought about changing your data structure? Without context, the IDs of the entries seem a little useless. Your question suggests you only want to store unique titles, so why not make them your keys?

Example:

```
"entries": {
    "jack": "ooo",
    "john": "ooo"
}
```

That way you can do an efficient `if newname in entries` membership test.

EDIT:

Based on your comment you can still preserve the IDs by extending the data structure:

```
"entries": {
    "jack": {
        "body": "ooo",
        "id": 1
    },

    "john": {
        "body": "ooo",
        "id": 2
    }
}
```

Comment: The IDs are useful.The structure of a new entry is {"body": "oooo", "title":"jack", "id":(auto generated according to length of dictionary)}

Answer (score 1):

This should work?

```
entry_dict = {
    "1": {"body": "ooo", "title": "jack"},
    "2": {"body": "ooo", "title": "john"}
}

def does_title_exist(title):
    for entry_id, sub_dict in entry_dict.items():
        if sub_dict["title"] == title:
            print("Title %s already in dictionary at entry %s" %(title, entry_id))
            return True
    return False

print("Does the title exist? %s" % does_title_exist("jack"))
```

As Christian Suggests above this seems like an inefficient data structure for the job. It seems like if you just need index ID's a list may be better.

Answer (score 0):

I think to achieve this, one will have to traverse the dictionary.

```
'john' in [the_dict[en]['title'] for en in the_dict]
```